# loading form with no action inside a div

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a form inside a div tag, but with `action=""`, and i want the result of form submission abppear in the same div, so i created this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#div1').delegate('form', 'submit', function() { // catch the form's submit events inside the div
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                 //$('#div1').html(response); // update the DIV
                $('#div1').fadeOut('slow',function() {
                            $('#div1').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                    });
        }
        });
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });
                });
```

however when i submit the form, nothing appears because the form has no action to be loaded, the same function works with other forms having action attribute, so my question is how to handle this case to make the form read the script in the same page when the form action is empty?

Comment: You're asking, what can you do when you don't have action, and you want to post to that action. maybe adding an action?

Comment: @gdoron, i tried adding the same file name in the action but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

first, all forms should always have an action.  Its invalid HTML to not.

however, if I understand your question that you want to post to the current page, then you can do this

```
    url: $(this).attr('action') || window.location.href, // the file to call
```

this will take the action attribute if available, or the href of the current window's location if an action is absent.

Comment: it just loads the whole page inside the div.

Comment: yes, thats what the response will do.  you've posted your form to that page.  You need some sort of server side language to serve up just the content you want.